# Comparing biological diversity before and after

Tags: population, ecology, diversity

I've got counts of two species in two treatments at two timepoints. I've got six replicates of each treatment.

I'd like to know how to compare treatment diversity.

As it is, I've calculated the change in Simpson's diversity between the two time points and used t-test to compare the distributions.

I found a page that recommends using exp(shannon index), as that's a measure "true diversity" - i.e., the numbers are more comparable.

Can I take "change in exp(Shannon)" and just t-test those distributions?

Comment: There is a large although often repetitive and dismaying literature on diversity in ecology, as you should know, and if one authority claims that one single measure is best, others will disagree or argue that the claim is at least contentious, if not meaningless. But positively I'd commend exp($H$) not because of this implausible claim (what is "true diversity" any way?) but because it has a nice interpretation as equivalent number of equally common species. But you can get a similar measure for Simpson's, depending on exactly what you calculate.

Comment: Whether you can push such measures into a t test depends on how they are distributed.  Regardless of that, with two species, you may be better off just using the species counts!

Comment: Also, I really can not and do not predict that exp($H$) will work better for you than reciprocating $\sum p_i^2$ where $p_i$ is the proportion of species $i$,

Comment: The problem with the species counts is that both species increase over time. I'm really interested in how they compete with each other in the different treatments.

Comment: Relative counts, then.

Comment: We're out of sync with comments+replies here. I'm now replying to "I really can not and do not predict that exp(H)...": It wouldn't be *worse* though, or would it?

Comment: Sorry, I have no crystal ball on this. It's surely easy to calculate both and see which works better in your terms.

Comment: Yes, easily done! I think exp(shannon) is better for my needs as I'm less interested in the degree of "dominance"; the competition equilibrium might have one species at low frequency. I *do* want to put more emphasis on "richness" than 1/gini-simpsons gives. Thanks for your guidance on this.